# Is there any way to handle new SWF loaded?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i would like to know if there is a way to handle new SWF or class loaded in the AVM..
expecially in system domain.

What i was thinking to do is like call

```js
 ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.parentDomain.getQualifiedDefinitionNames();
```

every second and check for new classes(comparing last call result with new one). I don't like this way because it's a waste of performances and i prefer detect SWF instead of classes.
Hoping for some response, regards

Comment: Who is loading this SWF?

Comment: I will load one SWF as first,suppose it's not possible know who will load others SWF

Comment: What does "check for new classes" mean? Expand on what is supposed to happen.

Comment: For example i can store in a variable the last return value of the above function call, then call it again after 1 second and check for new values